# I cant open one fragmnet with recyclerview.adaper from another fragment with recyclerview.adaper

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), MovieListAdapter.ItemClickListener {
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
            add(R.id.flMain, FragmentMovieList())
            commit()
        }
    }

    override fun onItemClick() {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
            replace(R.id.flMain, FragmentMoviesDetails())
            addToBackStack(null)
                .commit()
        }
     }
}
```

**FirstAdapter**

```
class MovieListAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieListAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private var list = listOf<Movie>()
    private var itemclick: ItemClickListener? = null

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.view_holder_movie,parent,false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val movie = list[position]
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            holder.avatar?.setImageDrawable(holder.itemView.context.getDrawable(movie.avatar))
            holder.years?.text = movie.years
            holder.heart?.setImageDrawable(holder.itemView.context.getDrawable(movie.heart_avatar))
            holder.genre?.text = movie.genre
            holder.star1?.setImageDrawable(holder.itemView.context.getDrawable(movie.star1))
            holder.star2?.setImageDrawable(holder.itemView.context.getDrawable(movie.star2))
            holder.star3?.setImageDrawable(holder.itemView.context.getDrawable(movie.star3))
            holder.star4?.setImageDrawable(holder.itemView.context.getDrawable(movie.star4))
            holder.star5?.setImageDrawable(holder.itemView.context.getDrawable(movie.star5))
            holder.review?.text = movie.reviews
            holder.name?.text = movie.name
            holder.time?.text = movie.time
            holder.rvActor?.apply { setOnClickListener{
                itemclick?.onItemClick()
            } }
        }
    }

    fun bindActors(newMovie: List<Movie>) {
        list = newMovie
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = list.size

    class ViewHolder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
        val avatar: ImageView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivMain)
        val years: TextView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvYears)
        val heart: ImageView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivHeart)
        val genre: TextView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvGenre)
        val star1: ImageView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivStar1)
        val star2: ImageView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivStar2)
        val star3: ImageView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivStar3)
        val star4: ImageView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivStar4)
        val star5: ImageView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivStar5)
        val review: TextView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvReviews)
        val name: TextView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName)
        val time: TextView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTime)
        val rvActor: RecyclerView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rvActors)

    }
    interface ItemClickListener{
        fun onItemClick()
    }
}
```

**SecondAdapter**

```
class MovieDetailAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieDetailAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private var listDetail = listOf<MovieDetail>()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.view_holder_actor, parent, false)
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MovieDetailAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val detail = listDetail[position]
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            holder.imageDetail?.setImageDrawable(holder.itemView.context.getDrawable(detail.imageDetail))
            holder.detailName?.text = detail.detailName
            holder.detailAge?.text = detail.detailAge
            holder.tag?.text = detail.tag
            holder.detailStar1?.setImageDrawable(holder.itemView.context.getDrawable(detail.detailStar1))
            holder.detailStar2?.setImageDrawable(holder.itemView.context.getDrawable(detail.detailStar2))
            holder.detailStar3?.setImageDrawable(holder.itemView.context.getDrawable(detail.detailStar3))
            holder.detailStar4?.setImageDrawable(holder.itemView.context.getDrawable(detail.detailStar4))
            holder.detailStar5?.setImageDrawable(holder.itemView.context.getDrawable(detail.detailStar5))
            holder.detailReviews?.text = detail.detailReviews
            holder.detailStory?.text = detail.story.toString()
            holder.actor1?.setImageDrawable(holder.itemView.context.getDrawable(detail.actor1))
            holder.actor2?.setImageDrawable(holder.itemView.context.getDrawable(detail.actor2))
            holder.actor3?.setImageDrawable(holder.itemView.context.getDrawable(detail.actor3))
            holder.actor4?.setImageDrawable(holder.itemView.context.getDrawable(detail.actor4))
            holder.nameActor1?.text = detail.nameActor1
            holder.nameActor2?.text = detail.nameActor2
            holder.nameActor3?.text = detail.nameActor3
            holder.nameActor4?.text = detail.nameActor4
        }
    }

    fun bindActorsDetail(newDetail: List<MovieDetail>) {
        listDetail = newDetail
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = listDetail.size

    class ViewHolder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
        val imageDetail: ImageView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageDetail)
        val detailName: TextView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.detailName)
        val detailAge: TextView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.yearsDetail)
        val tag: TextView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tag)
        val detailStar1: ImageView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.detailStar1)
        val detailStar2: ImageView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.detailStar2)
        val detailStar3: ImageView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.detailStar3)
        val detailStar4: ImageView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.detailStar4)
        val detailStar5: ImageView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.detailStar5)
        val detailReviews: TextView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.detailReviews)
        val detailStory: TextView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.detailStory)
        val actor1: ImageView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivDetail1)
        val actor2: ImageView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivDetail2)
        val actor3: ImageView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivDetail3)
        val actor4: ImageView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivDetail4)
        val nameActor1: TextView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDetail1)
        val nameActor2: TextView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDetail2)
        val nameActor3: TextView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDetail3)
        val nameActor4: TextView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDetail4)

    }
}
```

**FirstFragment**

```
class FragmentMovieList : Fragment() {

    private var recycler: RecyclerView? = null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movie_list, container, false)

        return view
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        recycler =  view.findViewById(R.id.rvActors)
        recycler?.adapter = MovieListAdapter()
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        updateData()
        super.onStart()
    }

    private fun updateData() {
        (recycler?.adapter as? MovieListAdapter)?.apply {
            bindActors(MovieData().getMovie())
        }
    }
}
```

**SecondFragment**

```
class FragmentMoviesDetails : Fragment() {

    private var recyclerDetail: RecyclerView? = null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movies_details, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        recyclerDetail =  view.findViewById(R.id.rvDetail)
        recyclerDetail?.adapter = MovieDetailAdapter()
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        updateData()
        super.onStart()
    }

    private fun updateData() {
        (recyclerDetail?.adapter as? MovieDetailAdapter)?.apply {
            bindActorsDetail(DetailData().getDetail())
        }
    }
}
```

I use list with some data for first adapter and second.
I did some actions so that when I clicked on the icon in the first fragment, I would go to the second fragment, but nothing would come up.
Without `recyclerview.adapter` transitions between fragments happened

Answer (score 0):

I also implemented the same thing i.e opening another fragment from a fragment with recycler view using navigation component. I can share my code so that you can get some references. So here is my code...

**Adapter**

```
class TheoryAdapter(private  var mlistner : onItemClickListener): RecyclerView.Adapter<TheoryAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    interface onItemClickListener{
        fun onItemClick(position: Int)
    }

    //my code (create & bind view holder)

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView),View.OnClickListener {
   //my code
        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
        }

        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            val position = bindingAdapterPosition
            if (position!=RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                if (v != null) {
                    mlistner.onItemClick(position)
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Fragment**

```
class TheoryFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_theory),TheoryAdapter.onItemClickListener {
 
//my code (onCreateView)

   override fun onItemClick(position: Int) {
        val pos = position
        val action = TheoryFragmentDirections.actionTheoryFragmentToTextDisplayFragment(pos)
        findNavController().navigate(action)

    }

}
```

**Nav Graph**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph.xml"
    app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/theoryFragment"
        android:name="com.example.learnjava.fragment.TheoryFragment"
        android:label="fragment_theory"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_theory" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_theoryFragment_to_textDisplayFragment"
            app:destination="@id/textDisplayFragment" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I can't figure out where you got the methods like, TheoryFragmentDirections.actionTheoryFragmentToTextDisplayFragment or bindingAdapterPosition, and how do you use this method onClick

Comment: TheoryFragmentDirections.actionTheoryFragmentToTextDisplayFragment , this is to go from main fragment to other fragment, i will suggest you to watch video on navigation component, its really a easy method to switch between fragment. And onClick method comes from adapter.